# Converting D3 path to points and not understanding output

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to convert a path (generated by D3) to points.  I'm using getTotalLength() and getPointAtLength() but the values I'm getting back are really odd.  getTotalLength() returns a huge value - 14594.1923828125.  Also, if I look at the individual values what I get don't seem to be in the coordinate space.  For example getPointAtLength(10000) returns negative values.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I not understanding about the returned values?

```
Here is my code
//The data for our line
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 30},  { "x": 20,  "y": 50},
                 { "x": 70,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                     .interpolate("basis");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 200)
                                .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                        .attr("stroke", "blue")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("fill", "none");

mySVG = d3.select("svg")
myPath = mySVG.select("path").node()
console.log(myPath)
console.log(myPath.getTotalLength())
console.log(myPath.getPointAtLength(10000))
```

And here is the jsfiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/atTxL/1/

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me -- length is 126.something and no negative values. Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks.  Just tested in IE and it looks good there as well.  It seems to be a FireFox (28.0) issue.  How odd.

Comment: Yep.  See this bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984796  Apparently it will be fixed again by Firefox 30.  In the meantime, it's breaking a lot of Javascript-based SVG animations/calculations.